# how to set setgid in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

In my ubuntu 14.04 lts, I tried  setgid command as root user but it give setgid not found, for setuid it says to install and I install . But for setgid it does not give any option. So how can I get this command in linux ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Are you talking about the setgid bit within the permissions or the system call setgid()?  Never heard of a setgid command.  What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: actually I don't know much about setgid, just heared and doing practice , could you please tell me about setgid to set for a directory, I am working as root user

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question.  My answer below..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When the setgid bit is set on a directory, new sub folders and files within that directory will inherit the group of the owner of the directory.  If you do this on a folder, you can force new files and folders to have your group id, even if another user does the creation.

You can turn the setgid bit on by running:

```
chmod g+s <directory name here>
```

The user and group can be displayed using in the parent directory.

```
ls -l
```

See: http://www.toptip.ca/2010/03/linux-setgid-on-directory.html

Comment: and where is group name or groupid in this

Comment: no I want to know in this command where to give my desired groupid

Comment: Oh you are trying to change the group of a file or directory?

Comment: from root I create a directory testdir, now I do chmod g+s testdir, then login to user1, now try to create a file under testdir. now it is not able to create file under this directory. so what is the benifit of setgid bit

Comment: You weren't able to create a directory because you did not have permissions on the directory.

The benefit of the setgid bit is in my answer.